# How to Get Logo to Align Left and Nav Links to Align Right?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying everything, I'm new at this and just cannot get it to work.
I just wanted my logo ("animated") to always align left, and the links to align right. Just like any normal nav bar.

The animated logo works just fine. I just can't separate the logo from the links and align them?

I've tried `float: right` and `margin-right: auto` under the animated logo.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 right;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  z-index: 50;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.animated-logo {
  display: flex;
  color: #000000;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: .15s;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

menu a {
  color: black;
  margin: 0 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
  padding: 8px 5px;
  border-radius: 99px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu a:hover {
  color: #808080;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="index.html" class="logo">
      <h3 class="animated-logo">
        <span class="letter first">t</span>
        <span class="letter">a</span>
        <span class="letter-hide">a</span>
        <span class="letter">r</span>
        <span class="letter">s</span>
        <span class="letter-hide">t</span>
        <span class="letter">r</span>
      </h3>
    </a>

    <div class="menu">
      <a href="about.html">About</a>
      <a href="experience.html">Experience</a>
      <a href="mailto:email">Contact Me</a>

    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `width: 100vw;` to the `.container`.

You only set `max-width`, which is not enough because the width will be "auto" if there's not enough content, but never more than `1280px`.

You want the width to be `100vw` if there's not enough content, but never more than `1280px`.

See the snippet below.

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw; /* Added */
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 right;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  z-index: 50;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.animated-logo {
  display: flex;
  color: #000000;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: .15s;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.menu a {
  color: black;
  margin: 0 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
  padding: 8px 5px;
  border-radius: 99px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu a:hover {
  color: #808080;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="container">
      <a href="index.html" class="logo">
        <h3 class="animated-logo">
          <span class="letter first">t</span>
          <span class="letter">a</span>
          <span class="letter-hide">a</span>
          <span class="letter">r</span>
          <span class="letter">s</span>
          <span class="letter-hide">t</span>
          <span class="letter">r</span>
        </h3>
      </a>

      <div class="menu">
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
        <a href="experience.html">Experience</a>
        <a href="mailto:email">Contact Me</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

---

**EDIT 1**

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw; /* Added */
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 right;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  z-index: 50;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.animated-logo {
  display: flex;
  color: #000000;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: .15s;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.menu a {
  color: black;
  margin: 0 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
  padding: 8px 5px;
  border-radius: 99px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu a:hover {
  color: #808080;
}

/* Added */
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="container">
      <a href="index.html" class="logo">
        <h3 class="animated-logo">
          <span class="letter first">t</span>
          <span class="letter">a</span>
          <span class="letter-hide">a</span>
          <span class="letter">r</span>
          <span class="letter">s</span>
          <span class="letter-hide">t</span>
          <span class="letter">r</span>
        </h3>
      </a>

      <div class="menu">
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
        <a href="experience.html">Experience</a>
        <a href="mailto:email">Contact Me</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

---

**EDIT 2**

Github 1440px:

[image: 1440px]

Github 2560px:

[image: 2560px]

Comment: Thank you SO much! This moved it over! Makes sense! There is still this space left once adding that - https://i.vgy.me/Z5gp5h.png - any way to move even further left when full screen, or is this as good as it gets? Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome. :) I edited my answer. Is it better now? Added `nav { display: flex; justify-content: space-around; }`.

Comment: Yes, thank you!  A gentle person and a scholar. I also removed max-width: 1280px; to get it perfect. Not sure if that'll be troublesome in the end, but this works! Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't say it's troublesome, but... Many websites have set `max-width`. If the screen is very big, the content is narrowed to the center of the screen. This is the point. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually use for navbars is a display: flex;
If I understood correctly what you want to do is organise the elements horizontally in the bar, to do that you can give the container class the following properties:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

If that doesn't suit your needs or if you want more informations about flex boxes I'd recommend this website: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
It explains all you need to know about flex boxes and could help you find a solution to your problem.